# How to split a data frame by row number?

Tags: r, split

My goal is to split a df such that row 1-21 is one data frame, and row 22-39 make up another data frame. 
I can't find how to do that anywhere.Thanks!

Comment: df1 <- df[1:21,] and df2 <- df[22:39,]

Comment: df1 = df[1:21,] for the first one. please post a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` using `data.table`. Assuming you want a more general version of your problem (where you bundle together every 20 observations)

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
split(df, by = floor(1:nrow(df)/20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split data frames by selecting just the rows or the columns that you need and associating them to a new object:

```
new_df1 <- df[1:21, ]

new_df2 <- df[22:39, ]
```